# Django 1 wrong migration messing up data model

Tags: python, django, database, datamodel

strange problem here that I replicated twice on my system this morning.  Working with django 1.9.2.

Very simply, I made changes to a model, I changed this:

```
class Sighting(models.Model):
        caption = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
        subspecies = models.ForeignKey(Subspecies, default=None, blank=True)
        lat = models.FloatField(default=None)
        lng = models.FloatField(default= None)
        #location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
        sighting_date = models.DateTimeField()
        image = models.ImageField(default=None)
        user_id = models.IntegerField(default=None)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.caption
```

to this:

```
class Sighting(models.Model):
        caption = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
        subspecies = models.ForeignKey(Subspecies, default=None, blank=True)
        species_tags = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
        lat = models.FloatField(default=None)
        lng = models.FloatField(default= None)
        #location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
        sighting_date = models.DateTimeField()
        image = models.ImageField(default=None)
        user_id = models.IntegerField(default=None)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.caption
```

I added the `species_tags` field to the model.  I ran `makemigrations` successfully, and then tried to `migrate` I got this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   birds_sighting.species_tags

So then I changed the model to this, adding `blank=True, null=True` to the new field:

```
class Sighting(models.Model):
        caption = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
        subspecies = models.ForeignKey(Subspecies, default=None, blank=True)
        species_tags = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
        lat = models.FloatField(default=None)
        lng = models.FloatField(default= None)
        #location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
        sighting_date = models.DateTimeField()
        image = models.ImageField(default=None)
        user_id = models.IntegerField(default=None)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.caption
```

I ran `makemigrations` again, which reflected a change then `migrate` again and it showed the same error.

I then went into the migrations folder and manually deleted the previous migrations that I made today, and then again ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` and it worked successfully.  I tested again twice and every time, if I added a field to the model initially without the `blank=True, null=True` properties set, and ran a `makemigrations`, simply fixing the model didn't allow me to migrate, I had to manually delete the previous migrations which caused the error.  I didn't think you had to do this, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations):

> You are encouraged to make migrations freely and not worry about how
>   many you have; the migration code is optimized to deal with hundreds
>   at a time without much slowdown.

I figure I am doing something wrong here in my workflow, and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In django, migrations that have not run previously, run in the order of the migration number, as displayed in the migration file name. When you try adding a new field without a `null=True`, the database throws an error as it expects some value for that column, for the existing rows.

Now since you know that this migration cannot be run, you create another one with `blank=True, null=True`. but, django still runs the migrations in order, again trying to run the first migration before running the second. So, you will always have to delete a wrong migration before running migrate

Comment: I thought that manually deleting the migrations seems kinda sloppy, and also that this kind of error will happen a lot, since I figure I will make a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you had previously created a model something like

```
subspecies = models.ForeignKey(Subspecies, blank=False)
```

or

```
subspecies = models.ForeignKey(Subspecies, unique = True)
```

and then removed it, which caused conflicts in your database schema